# Encode variable multiple times in a for loop in bash

Tags: bash

I want to encode the var 40 times to base64 and need the value of the 35th generated value. But it seems I get the same result for all 40 encodings (37). Can anyone get me on the right path? I tried everything so far..

```
#!/bin/bash

# Variable to encode
var="nef892na9s1p9asn2aJs71nIsm"
counter=0

for counter in {1..40}
do
   encode=$(echo $var | base64)
   ((counter++))

if [[ "$counter" == 35 ]]; then
    echo $encode | wc -c
fi
done
```

Comment: Remove `((counter++))`. `40 times to base64 and need the value of the 35th` Then why 40? Just do it `35` times. `all 40 encodings (37)` so 40, 37 or 35? `I get the same result` How do you check the result if it's the same? Please post it.

Comment: @raidn1337 : You always encode the same variable (`var`). Why do you think you would get different results? Actually, I would find it creepy if you would get different results on each attempt.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `var` each loop.

```
encode=$(echo $var | base64)
```

`var` is *always the same*, you never change it. Use `encode`, for example.

```
encode=$var
for ....
      encode=$(echo "$encode" | base64)
```

Check your scripts with shellcheck.net .